# EclEmma code coverage plugin in Eclipse unable to include all the modules of the project

Tags: java, eclemma

I am using EclEmma for code coverage tool. In coverage configurations,some of the imported projects are not available . I am unable to add them.

I tried to run coverage configuration for a particular module but there was no main class. So coverage can not be run. The only way to run coverage tool is from a module that contains main class.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to run module that does not contain main class to get coverage for it:

[image]